# libGDX build fails and does not let me build first file

Tags: libgdx

It gives the error

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'test'.

> com/github/jtakakura/gradle/plugins/robovm/RoboVMPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

How can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly did you do to get this error? Did you generate the projects with the gdx-setup? What do you mean by "first file"? Did you follow the documentation? There are even video tutorials by the creator of libgdx himself which show exactly how to do everything for 3 different IDEs + commandline...

Comment: Yes I checked the tutorials, but still no luck. I am on a Macbook so I just clicked start on the downloaded .jar file. By first file, i mean it is the first project that I am trying to import into Eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved just disabling Desktop, iOS, and HTML options. So you have to generate Android version only.

[image]

Comment: Though this is an old topic, it is still relevant, and solving an error by not building for other platforms (on a game development library meant to be used cross-platform) is a band-aid.

Answer (score 1):

You see this error because you do not have a JDK of 7 or above installed. The answer being listed [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/1603).

I came across the same issue when I had `openjdk-7-jdk` installed on my Debian system.

[To install Oracle Java 7 on Debian and derivatives](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-debian.html):

```
sudo echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
sudo echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```